# wxWidgets - How to not push back anything to a wxVector?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a application in which user can insert files into `wxDataViewListCtrl`, and have a database to store all the information about the files. And I have a function called `LoadDatabase()` to the load the database back to application, when user closes, and relaunches the application, which looks like this,

```
wxVector<wxVector<wxVariant>> Database::LoadDatabase(wxVector<wxVector<wxVariant>>& vecSet, wxTreeCtrl& favorite_tree, wxTreeItemId& favorite_item, wxTreeCtrl& trash_tree, wxTreeItemId& trash_item)
{
    try
    {
        if (sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &m_Database) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            wxLogDebug("Error opening DB");
            throw sqlite3_errmsg(m_Database);
        }

        std::string load = "SELECT FAVORITE, FILENAME, SAMPLEPACK, TYPE, \
                            CHANNELS, LENGTH, SAMPLERATE, BITRATE, TRASHED \
                            FROM SAMPLES;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_Database, load.c_str(), load.size(), &m_Stmt, NULL);

        if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int row = 0;

            while (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(m_Stmt))
            {
                wxLogDebug("Record found, fetching..");

                int c1 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 0);
                wxString c2 = wxString(std::string(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 1))));
                wxString c3 = wxString(std::string(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 2))));
                wxString c4 = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 3)));
                int c5 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 4);
                int c6 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 5);
                int c7 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 6);
                int c8 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 7);
                int c9 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 8);

                wxVector<wxVariant> vec;

                if (c1 == 1)
                {
                    vec.push_back(true);
                    vec.push_back(c2);
                    vec.push_back(c3);
                    vec.push_back(c4);
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c5));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c6));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c7));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c8));

                    favorite_tree.AppendItem(favorite_item, c2);
                }
                else if (c9 == 1)
                {
                    vec.push_back(false);
                    vec.push_back(c2);
                    vec.push_back(c3);
                    vec.push_back(c4);
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c5));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c6));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c7));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c8));

                    trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);
                }
                else
                {
                    vec.push_back(false);
                    vec.push_back(c2);
                    vec.push_back(c3);
                    vec.push_back(c4);
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c5));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c6));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c7));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c8));
                }

                vecSet.push_back(vec);

                row++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wxMessageDialog* msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot load data from table.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(m_ErrMsg);
        }

        rc = sqlite3_finalize(m_Stmt);

        sqlite3_close(m_Database);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }

    return vecSet;
}
```

What I want to do is, when `c9 == 1` don't push back anything to the vector. But if I don't push back to the vector, i.e comment all the lines in the `else if` statement, except `trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);` then it gives me error about index.

EDIT:
I call this `LoadDatabase()` as,

```
void Browser::RestoreDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        wxVector<wxVector<wxVariant>> dataset;

        if (db.LoadDatabase(dataset, *m_CollectionView, rootNode, *m_TrashedItems, trash_root_node).empty())
        {
            wxLogDebug("Error! Database is empty.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto data : dataset)
            {
                m_SampleListView->AppendItem(data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error loading data." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`SampleListView` here is `wxDataViewListCtrl`, I want that when `c9 == 1` don't return anything, just append that item's filename to `trash_tree`. Because if I push back anything to `vec` it will get added to `SampleListView`.

This is the error I get,
[image]

Comment: `else (c1 == 0)` is invalid.

Comment: As for your question, *which* vector don't you want to push back into? And if you mean the `vecSet` vector, then perhaps you get problems later because you increase and use `row` no matter the actual size of the vector (or otherwise assume some fixed size without actually checking)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What gives you an error (what error?) and what do you want or not want to push back?

Comment: Sorry copy paste error, forgot to remove `c1 == 0` after `else`. Yes, I don't want to push back anything to `vecSet` `if (c9 == 1)` but want to `trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);`.

Comment: @Devolus I basically have 2 `wxTreeCtrl` one for favorite items, another for trashed. `if (c1 == 1)` means if item is favorite then return vector and append that item's file name `c2` to `favorite_tree`, and `if (c9 == 1)` that means item is trashed, don't push back anything i.e don't insert that item back to `wxDataViewListCtrl`, but append that item's filename `c2` to `trash_tree`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question right, but do you mean like this?

```
wxVector<wxVariant> vec;

if (c9 == 1)
{
    trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);
}
else
{
    if (c1 == 1)
    {
        vec.push_back(true);

        favorite_tree.AppendItem(favorite_item, c2);
    }
    else
        vec.push_back(false);

    vecSet.push_back(vec);
    vec.push_back(c2);
    vec.push_back(c3);
    vec.push_back(c4);
    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c5));
    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c6));
    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c7));
    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",c8));
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post, sorry I'm not able to properly explain the problem, while trying to not over expand my post. The code you shared above, gives me the same error, I posted a screenshot of the error in the original post.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error, I posted a screenshot of the error in the original post. Also its hard to talk in comments, I'm posting another answer below to show the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code according to the one you shared above,

```
wxVector<wxVector<wxVariant>> Database::LoadDatabase(wxVector<wxVector<wxVariant>>& vecSet, wxTreeCtrl& favorite_tree, wxTreeItemId& favorite_item, wxTreeCtrl& trash_tree, wxTreeItemId& trash_item)
{
    try
    {
        if (sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &m_Database) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            wxLogDebug("Error opening DB");
            throw sqlite3_errmsg(m_Database);
        }

        std::string load = "SELECT FAVORITE, FILENAME, SAMPLEPACK, TYPE, \
                            CHANNELS, LENGTH, SAMPLERATE, BITRATE, TRASHED \
                            FROM SAMPLES;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_Database, load.c_str(), load.size(), &m_Stmt, NULL);

        if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int row = 0;

            while (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(m_Stmt))
            {
                wxLogDebug("Record found, fetching..");

                int c1 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 0);
                wxString c2 = wxString(std::string(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 1))));
                wxString c3 = wxString(std::string(reinterpret_cast< const char* >(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 2))));
                wxString c4 = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(m_Stmt, 3)));
                int c5 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 4);
                int c6 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 5);
                int c7 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 6);
                int c8 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 7);
                int c9 = sqlite3_column_int(m_Stmt, 8);

                wxVector<wxVariant> vec;

                if (c9 == 1)
                {
                    trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c1 == 1)
                    {
                        vec.push_back(true);

                        favorite_tree.AppendItem(favorite_item, c2);
                    }
                    else
                        vec.push_back(false);

                    vecSet.push_back(vec);
                    vec.push_back(c2);
                    vec.push_back(c3);
                    vec.push_back(c4);
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c5));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c6));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c7));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c8));
                }

                row++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wxMessageDialog* msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot load data from table.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(m_ErrMsg);
        }

        rc = sqlite3_finalize(m_Stmt);

        sqlite3_close(m_Database);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }

    return vecSet;
}
```

It gives me this error,

[image]

Also why pushing back to `vecSet` before pushing back the other items to `vec`.

EDIT:

After moving the line `vecSet.push_back(vec)` after we push everything to `vec` first, it seems to do what I was intending it to do.

```
                wxVector<wxVariant> vec;

                if (c9 == 1)
                {
                    trash_tree.AppendItem(trash_item, c2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c1 == 1)
                    {
                        vec.push_back(true);

                        favorite_tree.AppendItem(favorite_item, c2);
                    }
                    else
                        vec.push_back(false);

                    vec.push_back(c2);
                    vec.push_back(c3);
                    vec.push_back(c4);
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c5));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c6));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c7));
                    vec.push_back(wxString::Format("%d", c8));

                    vecSet.push_back(vec);
                }
```

So I guess its fixed now.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Of course the vector push has to come afterwards. BTW, the first line where `vec` is declared, can be moved to the top of the `else`.